# django Built-in template tags and filter Cut command not removing second space

Tags: python, html, django

My `database` stored phone numbers as "(123) 456-7890 "
I need to remove all spaces from a phone number so that I can make calls via Cisco phone.

```
`<td><a href="ciscotel:1{{contact.Phone|cut:" "}}" target="_self">{{` contact.Phone | cut:" "}}</a></td>
```

But django is displaying html as:

```
<a href="ciscotel:1(123)456-7890 " target="_self">(123)456-7890&nbsp;</a>
```

I tried :

```
{{contact.Phone|cut:"("|cut:")"|cut:"-"|cut:" "}}
```

and

```
{{contact.Phone|cut:"("|cut:" "|cut:"&nbsp;"}}
```

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#cut) makes it seem like one cut function should clear both spaces.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there's another white character at the end? I'd recommend using [`spaceless`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#spaceless) tag. According to docs, it:

> removes whitespace between HTML tags. This includes tab characters and
>   newlines.

```
{% spaceless %}{{contact.Phone|cut:"("|cut:")"|cut:"-"|cut:" "}{% endspaceless %}
```

**Edit:** as pointed by @iklinac in the comments below `|cut:" "` is still needed as `spaceless` is not allowed to modify variables you passed to the template.

Comment: It fixed the space at the end but not the space in the middle which I was able to fix using cut. If I use them both together it does the job:
ciscotel:1{% spaceless %}{{contact.Phone|cut:" "}}{% endspaceless %}

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, it should not modify the variables you passed to it. I'll modify the answer in case somebody else needs that one day. I'm glad you solved the issue.